# Find nodes at the edge of a BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Nodes at the edge of a BST are nodes: nodes with the biggest/smallest key among the same level nodes. (exclude the root and leaf nodes)

```
> Suppose we already have a BST like this:

                  --------5--------
                     -4--     -8---
                  -1-  -3-   -N-10-
                      -2-N-   -9--N-

So the nodes we need to find: 4,8,10 (don't use array/string)
```

I'm thinking about using stack to store the keys of the nodes. But it seems like I'm having trouble with popping and comparing to find the biggest/smallest. So could you help me think of any better solution?

Comment: I believe they are on the graphical edges.

Comment: @Aszune'sHeart yeah they're graphical

Comment: Unless I don't understand the question, this is straight forward.  So it will depend on what you want to do with the nodes after you extract them.

Comment: @AnonMail oh they'll be deleted one by one in ascending order of their keys.

Comment: If you are trying to save space, consider using a leaf node class that has no link field.

Comment: no i'm not. And i'm using struct here, not class.

Comment: Probably you can add a field for depth in your struct. Suppose you are trying to find the smallest on level $k$. If the left branch of the root has depth greater than $k-1$, then the desired element must be on the left branch. Otherwise it's on the right. And you can go down each level like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform level-order traversal (using queues).

Every time you dequeue, for the level in which you're, check if it's the smallest or the largest value that you've recorded so far.

While checking for the smallest and largest values, make sure root doesn't have both root.left & root.right as NULL

Comment: i figured it out using my stack with the same solution as yours. Thank you by the way.